# Oracle UCM - ridc - get all versions of document

Tags: content-management-system, oracle-ucm, webcenter

I am getting files from Oracle UCM via RIDC. I am using DataBinder as follows :

```
IdcClient client =getUCMConnection();
DataBinder dataBinder = client.createBinder ();
dataBinder.putLocal ("IdcService", "GET_FILE");
dataBinder.putLocal ("dID", dID);
IdcContext userContext = new IdcContext(username);
ServiceResponse response = client.sendRequest (userContext, dataBinder);  
InputStream fstream = response.getResponseStream ();

....... etc.
```

I want to ask, how can I get "ALL VERSIONS" of a document instead of latest released one?

Answer (score 3):

First you have to call the service [**DOC_INFO**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e11011/core.htm#autoId73), you can get the result set of the revision by using the **REVISION_HISTORY** set.

You will get specific dID for each version, you iterate them and use [**GET_FILE**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e11011/core.htm#BABFDEFH) with dID as a parameter for each one of them

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but I think the service you are looking for is GET_INFO, try it and check all the resultsets you get I'm pretty sure one of them has the info for all the document's revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service [REV_HISTORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e11011/c05_core003.htm#CSSRG2312) to get the result set REVISIONS which contains info of all the revisions.